# Python scrape with selenium element not found

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get a timestamp from a website but element can't be located. The b-gray-800 is a child from stories-list

```
details = driver.find_element("xpath","//div[@id='stories-list']")
res = details.find_elements("xpath","./div[@class = 'b-gray-800']")
for items in res:
    print(items.get_attribute('data-story-timestamp'))
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong

```
<div id="stories-list">
       <div data-story-style="bordered" data-story-timestamp="1667211688511493" data-story-type="picture_created" class="b-gray-800">
```

Comment: please share all your code including the link to the page you are working on

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xpath to locate an element, you dont have to transverse to that element, you can directly access that element no matter how deep it is.

Also, you are using deprecated methods in selenium.

For your case, I recommend using IDs and Classes to reach your goal:

```
details = driver.find_element(By.ID,"stories-list")
res = details.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"b-gray-800")
for items in res:
    print(items.get_attribute('data-story-timestamp'))
```

It should work.